# Elegant way to implement Login page in JSP

Tags: jsp, authentication

I'm a beginner in JSP web development. I have a login (Login.jsp) page for my webapp which has standard login controls (eg. Username, Password text-boxes, remember me checkbox and a Login button) what I want to attain is when user provides credentials, upon submitted the details, Authenticate.jsp is called, where the credentials are matched with database, if they're correct, session for that user is created and if credentials are incorrect. I redirect the user back to login page with `response.sendRedirect("./Login.jsp?status=fail");`

On the Login.jsp, the `status` parameter is always checked and when it gives value `fail` I have `<div>` below the textboxes which has message `User Name or Password Incorrect!`, is shown to user upon such failure. Is it safe to send such parameters via URL (for given purpose)? What is more appropriate or standard way to implement something like this? Also, when the user visits the Login page for the first time, looking for `status` parameter will throw `NullPointerException`. I have entire Login.jsp code for checking the parameter as below.

```
    try
    {
        String stat = request.getParameter("Status");
        if(stat.equalsIgnoreCase("fail"))
            msg = "Invalid Username or Password!";
        else
            msg = " ";
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        msg = " ";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

And that `msg` string object is wrote to that `<div>` as I mentioned. So if there's no `status` parameter found, it is assumed that user is visiting the page for the first time, and hence no message for wrong credentials will be shown.

I'm feeling this may not be the way how this is implemented in real systems.

Correct me.

Thanks.

**Note:** While searching the same query on the web, most of them had different JSP page for failed login, while I want to keep only single page for that.

Answer (score 1):

While doing professional development, you are much better-off using a security framework.
Both [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) & [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) are very good candidates for implementing security in your project.

Comment: I went through Apache Shiro's overview, I'll definitely give it a try. But I'm looking for a solution that can be used without any third-party framework, something which can be done just using Java EE APIs and nothing else.

Comment: If you don't use a framework, you'll end up doing a lot of work for real-world applications

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code `String stat = request.getParameter("Status");`

`stat` will always be `NULL` when ever `Login.jsp` is accessed. This is not correct way to implement this.

It is always suggested to implement `MVC` pattern where you have `JSP` for presentation and view purpose. `Servlets` to redirect requests and `Beans` as Model.

Here is some more explanation...

1) Separation of Concerns (SoC). Let your view (jsp) handle the rendering, Controller (servlet) handle the flow of the application, and all your processing in another set of classes. This would be the basics of MVC. Here is the wikipedia definition for a simple layout.

```
Model - The model is a collection of Java classes that form a software application 
intended to store, and optionally separate, data. A single front end class that can
communicate with any user interface (for example: a console, a graphical user interface,
or a web application).


View - The view is represented by a Java Server Page,
with data being transported to the page in the HttpServletRequest or HttpSession.

Controller - The Controller servlet communicates with the front end of the model and loads the HttpServletRequest or HttpSession with appropriate data,
before forwarding the HttpServletRequest and Response to the JSP using a RequestDispatcher.
```

You should create a Servlet which gets called from `Login.jsp` and then you get parameters from requests and then check for credentials.Then perform tasks like maintaining sessions after verifying credentials. Redirect from servlet to either `Login.jsp` with paramters  if wrong credentials are suppiled or to some other page once user is authenticated.

Comment: Can you provide sources where I can get detailed walkthrough on how it should be implemented?